# Filter data before loading it in an SSAS tabular model

Tags: hive, ssas-tabular

I have a dimension table to load from a hive table into an SSAS tabular project.
I just want to apply a filter on it while importing, to get data for 2020.
How can I reach this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the model, in table properties, change the Power Query to add the filter. For example :

[image]

Update your query to adjust your need. You could also click the design button to make the query in the Power Query Editor.

[image]